# Why my linked list is displaying garbage values

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

My doubly Linked list in C is displaying garbage value instead of value that I have entered, I have run this code on Turbo C++.
the code compiled correctly with 0 errors and 0 warnings, but still it is displaying some garbage values. I have included the libraries (stdio.h,conio.h,stdlib.h,malloc.h)
here is the code :

```
struct dlist
{
  int data;
  struct dlist *next;
  struct dlist *prev;
};

struct dlist *head, *end;

void create_dlist()
{
  char k='y';
  struct dlist *new_node;
  while(k=='y'||k=='Y') {
    if(head==NULL) {
      new_node=(struct dlist *)malloc(sizeof(struct dlist));
      printf("Enter the integer value -> ");
      new_node->data=0;
      new_node->next=NULL;
      new_node->prev=NULL;
      scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
      head=new_node;
      end=new_node;
    } else {
      new_node=(struct dlist *)malloc(sizeof(struct dlist));
      printf("Enter the integer value -> ");
      new_node->data=0;
      new_node->next=NULL;
      new_node->prev=end;
      scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
      end->next=new_node;
      end=new_node;
    }
    printf("Do you want to continue (y/n) ; ");
    scanf(" %c",&k);
  }
}

void display()
{
  struct dlist *pointer;
  pointer=head;
  if(pointer!=NULL) {
    while(pointer->next!=NULL) {
      printf("%d\t",&pointer->data);
      pointer=pointer->next;
    }
  } else {
    printf("list is empty");
  }
}

int main()
{
  clrscr();
  head=NULL;
  end=NULL;
  create_dlist();
  display();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

A coded solution will be a great help

Comment: For one thing, it looks like `display` is not showing the last element of the list.  For instance, if the list has exactly one element, the while loop will exit immediately before doing anything.

Comment: And `printf("%d\t",&pointer->data);` --> `printf("%d\t", pointer->data);`

Answer (score 2):

Whole problem is in `display()`. First you print address and not value of data. Also, you are not printing last element. I made some changes. Ask me if you need any explanations.

```
void display()
{
    struct dlist *pointer;
    pointer=head;
    if(pointer!=NULL)
    {
        while(pointer!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t",pointer->data);
            pointer=pointer->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("list is empty");
    }
}
```